# Storing callbacks with different value parameters always use the last value

Tags: javascript

I have a library the needs an array of buttons in order to produce a UI, this array has objects with a *Text* to show and a *callback* to call when the button is pressed. For this example as callback I'm using a console.log to show a value that gets randomly generated during the population of the array:

```
var buttons = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  var value = Math.random()*10;
  buttons.push({ 
    text: "Foo", 
    onTap: function() { console.log("Im a button and my value is", value) } })
}
```

As you can see right away since *onTap* gets called later on when the user taps the button, the value that console.log shows is the last one, meaning that all buttons will show the same value. I can modify the library to include some kind of meta field in the object where I can store the values and then retrieve them from the onTap function. But I prefer not to touch the library, is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: you should be able to achieve this by putting `button.push{...}` in IIFE as in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/71HksPY6Pp4gLMihCw9Z?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for is not scoped, so value is the last value always, you can scope the value by warping inside a function like below

```js
var buttons = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
 (function() {
  var value = Math.random()*10;
  buttons.push({ 
    text: "Foo", 
    onTap: function() { console.log("Im a button and my value is", value) } })
 })();
}
```

For your reference : https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

Or just use let instead of var

```js
var buttons = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  let value = Math.random()*10;
  buttons.push({ 
    text: "Foo", 
    onTap: function() { console.log("Im a button and my value is", value) } })
}
```

Comment: "for is not scoped" — We have `let` now.

Comment: Ya. I didn't state that because its not supported sometimes